# CSS in HTML more important than in style.css

Tags: html, css

I have prepared a page in HTML. I can only edit the HTML file - I cannot edit the CSS.

In the CSS file, there is a colour declared: `color: #fff000`. I created a new style in the HTML file. However, the CSS file `style.css` is more important - when I add a new color in the HTML page, the `style.css` colour overrides it.

Is there any possibility to set that CSS in the HTML as more important than the colour declared in `style.css`, without editing `style.css`?

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: Did you used In-line CSS style? Some code would help

Comment: If you are adding inline css then it should take priority

Comment: The use of `<link>` vs `<style>` vs `@import` has no bearing on the precedence of CSS.  You've misdiagnosed the problem.

Comment: Are you sure about that? Anything in the `style` tag found on the HTML will take precedence over anything in the CSS that was connected with a `link` tag. @Quentin

Comment: @slime — Yes, I'm sure and no, it won't.

Comment: Well I hate to break it to you, but you clearly a novice because that's exactly how it works. @Quentin Go test it yourself then come back.

Comment: Tested it myself: http://test-cases.dorward.me.uk/precedence/ - the `<link>` style sheet defines the div as blue while the style element defines it as red - and it is blue.

Comment: Your link tag is under the style tag, so it's the last load, so in that instance of course it will take precedence, but that's not a proper setup. The link tag should be above it anyways.

Comment: @slime — That's the point. The **order** of the stylesheets matters, the difference between `<link>` and `<style>` does not. There is no rule anywhere that says `<link>` should be defined before `<style>`.

Comment: @Quentin. There isn't a rule anywhere because it's common sense and implicit. Knowing the code is processed top-to-bottom, why would you have page specific styling overwritten by an external sheet? What's the point of having that page specific styling then? That's why you put it under the link so it pulls in all the global and then the custom stuff. If you had more experience under your belt you would learn that.

Comment: That's the point, it isn't a rule. It's *usually* best practise for the things that external and embedded stylesheets are *usually* used for. Now please stop telling me how little experience I have, the laughter is killing me.

Comment: The stupidity in this thread. It burns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline CSS always takes [precedence](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/) so if you put your styles directly on the HTML elements themselves, it should work:

```
<div id="title" style="color:white">Title</div>
```

This is acceptable, but not something I would do.

What I would recommend is making an overriding style sheet in the header of the HTML. This keeps the styling away from the HTML content, but you have to be sure to use the [`!important`](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/) tag to override the specificity. Adding the `!important` tag is not 100% required, since [internal stylesheet take precedence over external style sheets](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp) but it might be something to consider.

So, in the case of the earlier example, this would look something like:

```
<style>
#title {
    color: white!important;
}
</style>
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: What? This answer responds to: "Is there any possibility to set that css in html is more important than this style.css without editing style.css?"

Answer (score 1):

Inline CSS has more importance than a style.css rule. Maybe someone has added !important in the CSS though, then that would override your inline CSS. To try this out, do a:

```
<a href="#" style="color: red !important">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to set the css in html like this:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
    .more-important-style {
    background-color: #352e7e;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<style>` element with `scoped` attribute like this:

```
<style scoped="scoped" type="text/css">
    //Add rule here
</style>
```

Answer (score -3):

Generally speaking we can say that all the styles will "cascade" into a new "virtual" style sheet by the following rules, where number four has the highest priority:

```
1. Browser default
2. External style sheet
3. Internal style sheet (in the head section)
4. Inline style (inside an HTML element)
```

Comment: No, there is no difference between 2 and 3. You appear to be quoting W3Schools, they are wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure why you downvoted this, considering I'm right and you're wrong. I did quote them because no need to retype what is already out there.